# Check a Word in a Given String using Regular Expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently attempting to check if a specific word is contained in a user-entered string. I'm using Regular Expressions and have the following code:

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string input = @"oaaawaala";
        string word = "Owl";

        string pattern = Regex.Replace(word, ".", ".*$0");

        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

        var found = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options).Count > 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", found);
    }
}
```

The value of 'found' in the above code is true as the word 'Owl' is found in the input 'oaaawaala', based on the 'pattern'.

However, if I change the sequence of input to 'alaawaaao' or if the input is scrambled any other way, the value of 'found' is false since the pattern no longer matches. The Solution I need is that the 'word' should be found in any given string - scrambled or unscrambled. Any suggestions on how to go about this.

Thanks

Comment: So you are not interested in the word Owl, but rather O,w and l characters?

Comment: Yes, the individual characters

Comment: Do you need `o`, `w` and `l` to be matched in this order or in any order?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check that `input` contains all characters from `word`?

```
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string input = @"oaaawaala";
        string word = "Owl";

        var found = word.ToCharArray().Select(c => char.ToUpper(c)).Distinct().All(c => input.ToUpper().Contains(c));

        Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", found);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For regex solution, try this:

```
        string input = @"oaaawaala";
        string word = "Owl";
        if (Regex.IsMatch(input, Regex.Escape(word), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, Regex.Escape(word), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", matches[0].Groups[0].Value);
        }
```